# Execute statement inside conditional

Tags: twig, templating, shorthand

Is it possible to call an executable function inside a Twig conditional statement?

I have a path function and want to output the path if the name variable is empty. Right now I have these two options:

```
{% path file, 'reference' %} // calling path function
{{ file.name ?: file.path }} // Conditional
```

But I would like something like:

```
{% file.name ?: path file, 'reference' %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `path` is a tag instead of a function. If it was a function, you'd use it like this:

```
{% path(file, 'reference') %}
```

In comparison, Twig has a function `dump`, and in Symfony you can use a tag with the same name. Here's how you'd use them:

```
{{ dump(foo) }} {# function #}
{% dump foo %}  {# tag #}
```

You see the difference?

If `path` was a function, both of these would probably be possible:

```
{{ file.name ?: path(file, 'reference') }}
{% do file.name ?: path(file, 'reference') %}
```

Both are the same, except the second one doesn't print anything.

Because `path` seems to be a tag, I don't think it's possible to do what you asked. (It's also possible that it's both a tag and a function. If that's the case, use the function instead of the tag.)

*Edit:* Are you using Symfony? There's a [Twig function `path`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path) in Symfony, but I don't think there's a Twig tag `path`. Are you sure your code (`{% path file, 'reference' %}`) is correct?

Comment: Thanks @martias, so executing functions in a shorthand is possible. I just assumed path was a function.